# Number of ways to write positive integer as product of prime powers, not counting order of factors.

Tags: combinatorics

I need to find a formula for obtaining the number explained below:

$36 = 2^2 · 3^2$ Decomposition in primes

Then the posible reorganization are:

$2·2·3^2$

$2^2·3^2$

$2^2·3·3$

$2·2·3·3$

Giving a total of 4. (Keep in mind that order doesnt matter)
I need to find a way to know this number, without needing to perform all combinations.

Comment: Take a look at Multinomial coefficients.

Comment: @includeCMath I have!, but for the example set above, I get 6, which is not what I want, I believe its because of repetition, but dont know how to not count those that are the same but in different order

Comment: Please use more descriptive titles.

Comment: Your problem statement and your example don't match.

Comment: @includeCMath sorry, that´s the number Im interested in

Comment: "possible reordering" as in the problem statement leads to multinomial coefficients.

If I get your example right let's say $2 ^2\cdot 3^3$ would have as possible reorganization as $2^2 \cdot 3^2 \cdot 3$. Then you are interested in the number of partitions of the exponents

Comment: @includeCMath that´s true, thanks, I hadnt thought about the exponents. I dont really know how to get the number though, but I will give it a go with what you said. Thank you